# Perl, Can't locate Packet/UDP/Syslog.pm in @INC | custom modules

Tags: perl

Anybody please can spot a mistake here? I do have one perl script and 3 custom perl modules. I  specified location of the modules using export, also using -I, also inside the script using:

```
use lib '/var/pwn/syslog-generator/perl-modules/';
```

- but script still fails with common error:

  Can't locate Packet/UDP/Syslog.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /var/pwn/syslog-generator/perl-modules/ ./ /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at raw-syslog.pl line 5.
  BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at raw-syslog.pl line 5.
- modules are located here:

  ls /var/pwn/syslog-generator/perl-modules
  Packet.pm  Syslog.pm  UDP.pm

perl -V

```
Compiled at Sep 30 2013 03:45:34
  %ENV:
    PERL5LIB=":/var/pwn/syslog-generator/perl-modules/"
  @INC:
    /var/pwn/syslog-generator/perl-modules/
    /etc/perl
    /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2
    /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2
    /usr/lib/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5
    /usr/lib/perl/5.14
    /usr/share/perl/5.14
    /usr/local/lib/site_perl
```

And my perl script starts like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use lib './';
use lib '/var/pwn/syslog-generator/perl-modules/';
use Packet::UDP::Syslog;
use POSIX qw/strftime/;
```

- I also tryed to start the script with -Idirectory  [specify @INC/#include directory], but:

  perl -I /var/pwn/syslog-generator/perl-modules raw-syslog.pl
  Can't locate Packet/UDP/Syslog.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /var/pwn/syslog-generator/perl-modules/ ./ /var/pwn/syslog-generator/perl-modules /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at raw-syslog.pl line 5.
  BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at raw-syslog.pl line 5.

again, no luck. Something obvious I am missing?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure `Packet::UDP::Syslog` is actually installed at that location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have 3 modules in 3 files called Packet.pm, Syslog.pm, and UDP.pm?
Do they have   `package Packet;` ,  `package Syslog;` and `package UDP;` respectively at their top?

If so, you need to load each one of them separately using

```
use Packet;
use Syslog;
use UDP;
```

On the other hand, if you have one file in Packet/Syslog/UDP.pm then it has to have
`package Packet::Syslog::UDP;` at the top and you'd load it using

```
use Packet::Syslog::UDP;
```

Oh, and BTW, if this is up to you, I'd strongly recommend using a company or project specific module name-space. So instead of 'Packet.pm' I'd create a file called 'Company/Packet.pm' which would have `package Company::Packet;` at the top and I'd load it with `use Company::Packet;` Otherwise you'll easily bump into modules with the same name.

Some articles that might shed more light on the subject:

- [How to create a Perl Module for code reuse?](http://perlmaven.com/how-to-create-a-perl-module-for-code-reuse)
- [Packages, modules, distributions, and namespaces in Perl](http://perlmaven.com/packages-modules-and-namespace-in-perl)

(disclaimer: articles written by myself)

Answer (score 0):

When you `use Packet::UDP::Syslog`, Perl will mangle that name to the path `Packet/UDP/Syslog.pm`. It will then loop through the `@INC` directories and look for matches:

```
/var/pwn/syslog-generator/perl-modules/Packet/UDP/Syslog.pm
/etc/perl/Packet/UDP/Syslog.pm
/usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Packet/UDP/Syslog.pm
/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Packet/UDP/Syslog.pm
/usr/lib/perl5/Packet/UDP/Syslog.pm
/usr/share/perl5/Packet/UDP/Syslog.pm
/usr/lib/perl/5.14/Packet/UDP/Syslog.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.14/Packet/UDP/Syslog.pm
/usr/local/lib/site_perl/Packet/UDP/Syslog.pm
./Packet/UDP/Syslog.pm
```

If none of those files exists, the module hasn't been found. However, you only have these files:

```
/var/pwn/syslog-generator/perl-modules/Packet.pm
/var/pwn/syslog-generator/perl-modules/Syslog.pm
/var/pwn/syslog-generator/perl-modules/UDP.pm
```

That's not correct because the file system hierarchy is relevant when resolving namespaces. I suggest you properly install your module rather than copying files into a directory. You can use `cpan` or `cpanm` to install the module, and can use `local::lib` to install to a custom module location.